# Image Post to Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I am working on WPF application. I want to post image I select from OpenFileDialog. and I want to return url

**URL should be like this :** 
http://localhost:52185/api/Images/123456.jpg

**But my url :** 
http://localhost:52185/api/Images/DD8609E3-58A0-E811-B814-D050994A8C7D

How can I save images to localhost?

**Post Method :**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(ImageDTO request)
{
    var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(request.Image);
    HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(buffer);

    using( var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[objFile.InputStream.Length + 1];
        objFile.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = request.Name };
        content.Add(fileContent);
        objFile.SaveAs("http://localhost:52185/api/Images/1.jpg");
    }
    return Ok("http://imageurl");
}
```

**Client :**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
    fileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
    fileDialog.ShowDialog();

    var img = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName));

    HttpClient cli = new HttpClient();
    var url = "http://localhost:52185/api/Images";
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "image", img } };
    var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

    var response = await  cli.PostAsync(url, encodedContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned at which stage you have difficulties, I would assume you have managed to read input stream correctly. You may still need to modify this code to fit your coding style.

```
string f = @"C:\yourfolder\yourfile.png"; // @"c:\yourAPIRoot\Images\1.jpg
using (var binaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(objFile.InputStream))
{
    byte[] fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(objFile.ContentLength);
    using (System.IO.FileStream FileStream1 =
         new System.IO.FileStream(f, System.IO.FileMode.Create,
                                  System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
        FileStream1.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
        FileStream1.Close();
    }
}  
//return "http://localhost:52185/api/images/1.jpg"
return "http://yourdomain.com/yourfolder/yourfile.png"; //modify this to your return type
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use the virtual path in `SaveAs` method, also what is the purpose of `bytes/fileContent` in your code? plus `/api/` is kinda non-physical address, I am NOT sure whether this will work or not, anyhow, you can change your method to something like this,

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(ImageDTO request)
{
    var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(request.Image);
    HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(buffer);

    // full virtual path of the image name
    // TODO: right now, request.Name is assumed to be the image file name
    var virtualPath = string.Format("/api/Images/{0}.jpg", request.Name);

    using( var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        // **** I am NOT sure what is the purpose of bytes/fileContent here ****
        byte[] bytes = new byte[objFile.InputStream.Length + 1];
        objFile.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = request.Name };
        content.Add(fileContent);
        // here we are converting the virtual path to physical path
        var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
        objFile.SaveAs(physicalPath);
    }
    // I guess here you want to return the newly created path for the image
    return Ok(virtualPath);
}
```

Comment: but i think client is not working. because when i set breakpoint , it doesn't work

Comment: @EmreD. if you are talking about `Button_Click` event handler, then it's a separate issue, since I use the JS directly for the client side, so I am NOT really sure why your break-point is NOT hitting.

Comment: it is a wpf application and i have never used asp.net web api

Comment: Your question tags are NOT reflecting WPF, you should add that and you may need to post a separate question for the button click problem.

Comment: someone removed WPF tag